# How to read user name in Blazor WebAssembly App template

Tags: blazor

I created a Blazor WebAssembly app from template (templates 3.1.7).

I checked ASP.NET Core hosted and changed authentication to individual user accounts.

How can I read the user name in the api? `User.Identity.Name` is null

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject the AuthenticationStateProvider.

Please see the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

This will enable you to get the authentication state which contains the user:

```cs
        var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
```

Comment: This seems to be answer for component not server side

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by component and server side.

The main differences are web assembly and server side.

The article refers to both.

Comment: By server side I mean in API Controller.